# Remote install vbs in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, remote-access

i recently started to learn powershell and this is kinda my first project. I am trying to automated remote installation. I try to look for solution everywhere, but i cant find the right one. Here is the problem:

I need to instal multiple applications that have multiple version on remote computers.

I try few things but nothing worked so far :(

This one worked for me, but only if i don't use variables. If i use them PS (or i guess cscript.exe) does not recognize them.

```
$hostname = "yourPc"

$app= "app_0001"

$ver = "v1.0.0"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock {cscript.exe \\$hostname\directory\install.vbs /p:$app /v:$ver}
```

So i basically end up with `\\$hostname\directory\install.vbs /p:$app /v:$ver` does not exist. Is it possible to this with cscript.exe?

Thanks.

Comment: install.vbs exist sur every PC? Else put your script into a public share and use public share path for run your command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the script block win run *on the remote computer*, so it won't have access to your local variables.

You can either add the `using:` scope modifier to the variables that you want PowerShell to copy to the remote computer:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock {
  cscript.exe \\$using:hostname\directory\install.vbs /p:$using:app /v:$using:ver
}
```

... or you can explicitly pass values as *parameter arguments* to the remote scriptblock via the `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock {
  param($Path,$Application,$Version)

  cscript.exe \\$Path\directory\install.vbs /p:$Application /v:$Version
} -ArgumentList $hostname,$app,$ver
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot! :)